# In PowerShell, How to refer to a cmdlet itself rather than executing it?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm currently learning [Powershell 101](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/00-introduction?view=powershell-7.3) using PowerShell 7.4, and I'm interested in inpecting the type of some expressions, for example by executing

```
 [Powershell] | gm
```

I get:

```
 TypeName: System.RuntimeType
```

or by executing

```
[Powershell].getType()
```

I get

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name            BaseType
-------- -------- ----            --------
False    False    RuntimeType     System.Reflection.TypeInfo
```

However, I can't get the type of a Cmdlet since it's executed automatically, for example :

```
 get-help | gm
```

this command give the members of the returned object, rather than the members of the Cmdlet itself.

---

I tried executing:

```
(Get-Command Get-Help).GetType()
```

I got:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name          BaseType
-------- -------- ----          --------
True     False    CmdletInfo    System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo
```

So I think that the `Get-Command` Cmdlet does not return an object of type `Cmdlet` , instead, it gives a `CmdletInfo`  object.

---

According to the [Powershell SDK 7.4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.cmdlet?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0), the class of a Cmdlet is  `System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet`

```
[System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet]
```

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name   BaseType

-------- -------- ----   --------

True     False    Cmdlet System.Management.Automation.Internal.InternalCommand
```

---

So how can I refer to a Cmdlet itself in Powershell instead of executing it to play with its features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.ImplementingType` property of the [`System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo) instance returned by [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command):

```bash
(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType
```

This directly returns a [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type)-derived instance that represents the .NET type that implements the `Get-Help` cmdlet, namely [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand).

Every time you call `Get-Help` from PowerShell code, an instance of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand` is created behind the scenes.

As you note, all cmdlets must derive from the [`System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet) base class; the [`System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet) class (which itself derives from the former) is more typically used as the base class, as it provides better integration with the PowerShell runtime.

---

While you can directly *obtain an instance of* a cmdlet-implementing type as follows in order to inspect its properties, note that you won't be able to call `.Invoke()` on instances of `PSCmdlet`-derived types, which the majority of the built-in cmdlets are:

```bash
# Create an instance of the class that implements the `Get-Help` cmdlet.
$cmdletInstance = 
  (Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType::new()

# Ditto, using the type directly:
$cmdletInstance = 
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand]::new()
```

A - rare - example of where calling `.Invoke()` *does* work is the `Cmdlet`-derived `Get-Date`:

```bash
# Same as calling `Get-Date`
(Get-Command Get-Date).ImplementingType::new().Invoke()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! But I'd like to know exactly how to refer to a Cmdlet itself, in order to play with its features :)  It seems that `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType` is also a RuntimeType, not a Cmdlet type. See what `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType.getType()` returns.

Comment: @Saturn: Don't apply `.GetType()`: what you get already _is_ the type of interest - please see my update.

Comment: Indeed it's a representation of the `Get-Help` Cmdlet, but it's not the `Get-Help` cmdlet. Because if it were the `Get-Help` cmdlet, the type of `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType` would be `GetHelpCommand`.

Comment: In other words, `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand` is a class, and `Get-Help` is an instance of it. I would like to figure out the reference of the `Get-Help` instance.

Comment: @Saturn: `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType` _is_ the `GetHelpCommand` type: try `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType.Name` (or `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType.FullName`). Also: `(Get-Command Get-Help).ImplementingType -eq [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand]`

Comment: @Saturn: Re your latest comment: yes.

Comment: Thanks for your verification :) I'd wait for the reference of the `Get-Help` instance.

Comment: @Saturn What exactly are you hoping to achieve by obtaining a reference to an instance of a cmdlet?

Comment: Just for fun. I'm wondering if there is a way of obtaining a reference to an instance of a cmdlet ^^

Comment: @Saturn: Please see my update and note the limtiations.

Comment: @Saturn Here you go, have some fun: `$getHelpInstance = [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand]::new()` :)